Centrifugal force pointing toward the axis of rotation in MTW?
Describing the Eötvös experiment in Box 1.2 of Gravitation, MTW say that the acceleration dragging the observed mass away from its normal world line has two components:

a vertical one, directed upwards and produced by the supporting thread;
one directed toward the axis of rotation of the Earth.

My problem is with the second component. It appears to be centrifugal, because the magnitude (given by $\omega^2 \,R \,sin \,\theta$, $\theta$ being the colatitude) is greatest at the equator. Shouldn't it then be directed away from the axis of rotation of the Earth?

The inertial frame here is the mass in a (hypothetical) free fall. From this frame of reference, there is an upward vertical acceleration due to gravity, and a centripetal acceleration due to the Earth rotation.
If we forgot for a moment the vertical gravity force, the free movement of the mass would be to go away from the axis of rotation. So, in relation to this free movement, considered zero acceleration, it is accelerated in the opposite direction.

But the Earth rotation itself doesn't apply any force to the mass so as to produce a centripetal acceleration. The only thing that can do that is the Earth's gravity (component 1 in MTW's explanation). Or am I missing something?

If the Earth didn't rotate, the thread would be directed to its centre. Due to the rotation, its is slightly inclined. The horizontal component of the tension is the centripetal force that avoids the mass to escape South (the experiment was made in Budapest).

I guess I'm still in the dark because I don't see why the rotation should cause the thread to incline.

It is like a carousel. Faster the angular velocity, bigger the inclination of the cables to outside. The horizontal component of the tension in the cables is the centripetal force.

Still can't see how this carousel-like pull towards the center differs from newtonian gravity, and if it's just gravity, then: (i) the pull is towards the center of the Earth, not its axis, and (ii) it's already dealt with by component 1 of MTW's explanation, hence no point in making it appear again in component 2.

The centre of the centripetal force is in the axis, but not in the centre of the Earth, except if the lab is in the equator.

But again, what exactly is pulling the mass toward the axis in Eötvös' experiment? In a carousel it's quite easy: the structure pulls the horses, then the horses pull the children.

Oh, I see! The centrifugal force does indeed have a southward component for an experiment performed in the northern hemisphere. That explains everything.
